# Can't install WordPress Plugin: Request Timeout

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to install Wordpress plugin. Whenever I try to install manually, it says server timeout. It starts uploading but at the end fails. Please help me out. I am trying to install plugin latest Chrome.

Comment: Do you have the name of the plugin? Have you tried to upload the plugin via FTP?

Comment: When I read "try to install manually" I assume you downloaded the plugin and cd it into the plugins directory. But then you say "uploading" and I'm lost.

Comment: I am uploading to the plugin with Wordpress>add new plugin. It's because my website is on hosting in Bluehost.